# Installation of TFLearn on windows system

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda, tflearn

> > pip install tflearn, works, meaning tflearn gets installed, and I was able to import it, but a complex program doesn't run.

Error is related to _curses.

I tried installing _curses using whl files.

I get not a supported wheel file.

I tried installing anaconda. conda command is not recognized.

What should I do? Any full proof answers?

Comment: which version of tflearn you are installed

Comment: and show actual error

Comment: I solved it finally. I installed all the wheel files manually, even curses.

Comment: to share the solution.that helps to others